# Solving for $x$ in an equation with a summation symbol

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How can find the appropriate value of $x$ in the following infinite sum?
$$ \sum x + (x+10) + (x+20) + (x+30) + ..... (x+90) = 530$$

Comment: There is no *infinite* sum here and the sigma symbol on the left shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum x + (x+10) + (x+20) + (x+30) + ..... (x+90) = 530<=>$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^9(x+10n)=530<=>$$

$$10x+450=530<=>$$

$$x=\frac{530-450}{10}<=>$$

$$x=8$$

Answer (score 5):

This is an Arithmetic Series with common difference $=10$ and the number of terms being also $10$

Using the summation [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum),

$$\sum_{r=0}^9(x+10r)=\dfrac{10}2\left(x+\underbrace{x+90}\right)$$

Comment: 10x + 450 = 530 => 10x = 80 then x = 8

Comment: However I have one more question regarding actually.. how did you do [x (x+90)]'s (x+90)?

Comment: @Martijn, Please follow the hyperlink in the answer

Comment: Thanks so much now I've got it completely, looks like I've missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this as

$(x+0)+(x+10)+(x+20)....(x+90)=530$

$10x+(10+20+30...90)=530$

$10x+450=530$

$x=8$